# Simple referral system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a very simple referral system, but the issue I'm seeing is that I need to make two different calls to the DB with a single submit action and I'm not sure how to do that.

The general idea for the system is as follows:

- A visitor subscribes to the mailing list and receives an email with a referral link with some kind of query string parameter identifying them (e.g. www.domain.com?referrer_id=1)
- When another visitor uses this referral link and signs up, I store a) the new subscriber's email address, and b) the referral information

This would be stored in two tables:

- `subscribers` table with `| id | email | referrer |`
- `referrals` table with `| id | subscriber_id | referrals |`, where referrals is the number of times a subscriber has referred other subscribers

Again, I'm wondering how to make two calls -- one for the new subscriber and one for the referral information -- with a single submit action. Or, if that's not the best approach, how to do this using best practices.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you try to submit? Why both of these actions should be done in a single operation?

Comment: @DmitryTonkonogov To be honest, I'm new to development and this is the only way I know how to do it. How can these actions be done separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your scenario, you only need a single table for your users(subscribers):

```
|id  |email        |... |referred_by  |
|5   |user5@x.com  |... |1            |
|6   |user6@x.com  |... |5            |
|7   |user7@x.com  |... |5            |
|8   |user8@x.com  |... |6            |
```

The link that you will send to `user5`, to share it with his friends will be:

```
www.domain.com/users/sign-up?referred_by=5
```

Then, when anybody opens this link, the sing-up action with a single database query will create a new user with the `referred_by` value equals 5(the id of the referrer):

```
User.create!(email: 'xyz@x.com',... ,referred_by: 5)
```

You can modify the user(subscriber) model to be like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
....

  belongs_to :referrer, :class_name => 'User', foreign_key: 'referred_by'

  def number_of_referred_users
    where(referred_by: id).count
  end
....
end
```

Then in anytime you want to get the number of users that a certain user referred to your site:

```
user.number_of_referred_users
```

And, if you want to get the referrer of a certain user you can say:

```
user.referrer
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this -- super simple and easy.  Two quick questions:  - Doesn't `number_of_referred_users` need to take an argument (i.e. `id`)?  - How would I access and run that method?

Comment: @SpencerK. You r welcome. For the number_of_referred_users method, it is an instance method not a class method, so you will call it on the user that you have. e.g. `u = User.first; u.number_of_referred_users`. I think you have to read about Class method VS Instance Method http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: In the number_of_referred_users method, where needs to be called on the User model. It should be `User.where(referred_by: id).count`. The reason is that this is an instance method, but where is being called on the class, so the User model needs to be specified.